# Installing Ms-Access 2003 standalone?

Tags: ms-access

Anyone knows if it is possible to install Access 2003 standalone without the rest of the Office 2003? I seem not to locate my installation disks to test this out, but thought someone might have an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I believe so, when you install Office and choose custom install, you can deselect everything except Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a custom install and then deselect everything.

You will basically get all the MS Office run-time and shared components with only the Access application available to run.

Note: I don't use the access run-time any more, but do use it regularly for the Excel and/or Word applications.

Comment: MS Query is not used by Access, only by other Office apps, so I wouldn't say it's of any use at all for an Access-only installation.